# Efficient RC6 and Mars encryption algorithm implementions

Tags: c, linux, encryption, linux-kernel, cryptoapi

I am running linux kernel 2.6.32 which does not provide rc6 and mars encryption algorithms in its crypto API and I need to embed these algorithms as kernel modules and register them in linux's crypto API.

One way is to write my own implementation of these algorithms but I dont want to re-invent the wheel so I need to know whether there is any widely used implemention of these algos in C? I know there cant be a definite answer to this one but still if any of you gurus can tell me about some of the best open source implementations. It would be very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need these two obscure, old ciphers in the kernel?

Comment: were'nt they finalists of AES? Twofish and Serpent are also present in crypto API.

Comment: They were AES finalists… but that was in 1999. That was 14 years ago. There is no reason to use those ciphers today.

Comment: My point is that if crypto API can have twofish and serpent (both AES finalists) then why not mars and RC6? In any case If need to have these algos in kernel for educational puposes.

Comment: Web search?  I see many implementations.  Apparently they may have royalties.  I guess this is why they are not in Linux.  Who wants to pay for something you would not normally use? Eg; [Mars](http://embeddedsw.net/Cipher_Reference_Home.html#MARS), [RC6](http://www.schneier.com/sccd/RC6.ZIP), etc.

Comment: @artlessnoise I have seen many implementations on web as well but I am unable to chose from them, thats why I was asking here whether any one knows of a widely used C implementation of these algos so I can use them to get the best results possible.

Comment: So you want the best performance?  You might annotate the question to be more specific and specify which arch.  Different *C* constructs often give different performance depending on the target arch.  Or do you think there are algorithm improvements over the submitted code?